# I want to show a 4*5 matrix and my program is no error,but when I run it show me the program stop work

Tags: fortran

my program display no error but it can't work?

```
    program hw4
    dimension a(i,j)
    real a
    common i,j
    integer i,j
    do i=1,4,1
    do j=1,5,1
    a(1,1)=0
    a(1,2)=1
    a(1,3)=2
    a(1,4)=3
    a(1,5)=25
    a(2,1)=1
    a(2,2)=1
    a(2,3)=1
    a(2,4)=1
    a(2,5)=12
    a(3,1)=2
    a(3,2)=0
    a(3,3)=3
    a(3,4)=1
    a(3,5)=19
    a(4,1)=3
    a(4,2)=4
    a(4,3)=0
    a(4,4)=6
    a(4,5)=41
    write(*,*) a(i,j)
    enddo
    enddo
    stop
    end
```

I expect it will show 4*5 matrix,but now it will show me the program stop work message

Comment: 2 gratuitous comments (i) always include the line `implicit none` in your Fortran programs (as @jcerar has done in the answer below), and (ii) don't use `common` blocks in any new code you write.  The reasons for these rules are well explained in a myriad questions and answers here on SO and in any good modern tutorial material.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your matrix "a" must have constant shape i.e. dimensions "i" and "j" must be explicitly defined.

Secondly, your nested loop sets matrix values every loop. Try putting it before the loop.

Something like:

```
program hw4
  implicit none
  integer, parameter      :: ni=4, nj=5
  real, dimension(ni,nj)  :: a
  integer                 :: i, j

  ! Set matrix values here
  a(1,1) = 0
  ! ... 

  do i = 1, ni, 1
    do j = 1, nj, 1
      write(*,*) a(i,j)

    end do
  end do

end program hw4
```

Kind regards

Comment: @VladimirF thank you for comment. I adjusted the code.